# Streaming large volume of data over http

Tags: java, http, streaming, bigdata

I need to read about millions of xmls (about few gbs 
) and stream them over http via rest GET call with low latency. What would be the options to achieve this with java and/or open source tools.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for the [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class.

Comment: Please add more reference to what you have tried and add more detail to the question

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do streaming attachment over SOAP using MTOM. See [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/vijaya/streaming-soap-attachments-using-mtom-v2)